# Using regex in Powershell scripting to verify if a value is like another

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a Powershell script using a `-like` to do a value comparison.  I can write the regex using traditional regex methods and it works in the [online testers I've used](https://regexr.com/3c0lf) but I cannot get it to work in my script.  I suspect it's simply a syntax thing but all the sites I've referenced don't address scripting specifically.

I'm checking namespaces to see if there are matches.  For example,

[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
[www.itdomain.com](http://www.itdomain.com)
[www.anotherdomain.com](http://www.anotherdomain.com)
[www.somedomain.com](http://www.somedomain.com)

In this example, I'd like to match only the first two options.  This regex works at the tester mentioned above,
`\.(it)?domain\.`

Writing this in my script adds a small complication because the value "domain" is in a variable, so I've tried,

`$domainUrl -like "*.(it)?$($domain).*"` but the results are always `false`.

What am I missing in the Powershell syntax?

Comment: What if the input string is like `itdomain.com.lol.not.really.biz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) operator matches against [*wildcard patterns*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), not [*regexes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions).

You want the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator.

Your pattern, `"*.(it)?$($domain).*"`, is actually a *mix* of these two pattern languages, which won't work.

Presumably, you meant something like the following:

```bash
$domain = 'domain'

'www.itdomain.com' -match "\.(it)?$domain\." # -> $true
```

Note that `-match` - unlike `-like` - matches *substrings* by default, so there's no need to consume the input string *as a whole* with a given regex.

That is, the above matches a literal `.` (which must be escaped as `\.` in a regex) followed by either `itdomain` or `domain` (`(it)?` matches `it` *if present* (`?`)) and another literal `.` anywhere in the input string. For details, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/9NxbTR/1).
(The regex could be refined to make the matching more robust.)

For details on `-like` (wildcards) vs. `-match` (regexes), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54992835/45375).